# How can I access the parent Component in Blazor server-side?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I am using the server-side of blazor.

Here is a child Component which named Child:

```
<div class="Child">
    <img @OnClick="ShowFullImage" src="/img/aaa.jpg"/>
</div>
@code{
   private void ShowFullImage(){}
}
```

And here is a Parent Component:

```
<Child></Child>
<img id="FullImage"/>
```

The child Component is about to display the thumbnail. When the user clicks the thumbnail(just the `img` in the child Component), the full image will display in the `img` of parent Component which named FullImage.

Now the question is although I can add an `onlick` function in the child component, I don't know how to access its parent component yet.

Comment: Im not understading what you're trying to achieve with the full image but I would recommend see this blog [here](https://chrissainty.com/3-ways-to-communicate-between-components-in-blazor/).

Comment: If you need something specific from the parent component, pass it through the child component as a parameter. Other than that, it is really unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @LOLJovem  Thank you. The blog you provided is helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is `EventCallback`

```
// Child
<div class="Child">
    <img @onclick="ShowFullImage" src="/img/aaa.jpg"/>
</div>

@code{
   [Parameter]
   public EventCallback ShowFullImage { get; set; }
}
```

```
// Parent
<Child ShowFullImage="@ShowFullImage" />

@code{
    public void ShowFullImage()
    {
        // do what you want
    }
}
```

Comment: There is one more question. I have to transfer the src of image from child Component to parent Component. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Well, I found the solution in https://chrissainty.com/3-ways-to-communicate-between-components-in-blazor/ yet.